# My Notification won't show when set up date is the date today

Tags: android, firebase, notifications

I'm trying to show my users notifications through my service that checks my database when an item is at it's set date it should send a notification. My problem is that when the date comes it doesn't send a notification.

```
databaseReference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Groups").child(mGroupUid).child("HomeFragment").child("FreezerItems");
    childEventListener = databaseReference.addChildEventListener(new ChildEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onChildAdded(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {

            HashMap<String, String> value = (HashMap<String, String>) dataSnapshot.getValue();
            if (value != null) {
                String name = value.get("Name");
                String date = value.get("Date");

                SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("M/dd/yyyy", Locale.US);

                    try {
                        dateFormat = sdf.parse(date);

                    } catch (ParseException e) {
                        Log.wtf("FailedtoChangeDate", "Fail");
                    }

                    Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
                    cal.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, 1);
                    Date tomorrow = cal.getTime();

                    if (dateFormat.equals(tomorrow)) {

                        GoogleSignInAccount account = GoogleSignIn.getLastSignedInAccount(getApplicationContext());
                        if (account != null) {
                            String firstname = account.getGivenName();
                            mContentTitle = "Your " + name + " is about to be expired!";
                            mContentText = firstname + ", make sure to cook or eat your " + name + " by " + date;
                        }

                        Intent openApp = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MainActivity.class);
                        PendingIntent contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(getApplicationContext(), 100, openApp, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

                        notification = new NotificationCompat.Builder(getApplicationContext(), "Default")
                                .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_restaurant_black_24dp)
                                .setContentTitle(mContentTitle)
                                .setContentText(mContentText)
                                .setLights(Color.GREEN, 2000, 1000)
                                .setPriority(NotificationCompat.PRIORITY_MAX)
                                .setStyle(new NotificationCompat.BigTextStyle().bigText(mContentText))
                                .setContentIntent(contentIntent)
                                .setAutoCancel(true);
                        createNotificationChannel(getApplicationContext());

                        NotificationManagerCompat notificationManager = NotificationManagerCompat.from(getApplicationContext());
                        notificationManager.notify(uniqueID, notification.build());

                    }


            }

        }

        @Override
        public void onChildChanged(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onChildRemoved(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onChildMoved(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }
    });
```

I'm sure my notification works because when I remove `if (dateFormat.equals(tomorrow))` it sends a notifciation and works perfectly. This is also a service class and not a normal activity so maybe that has something to do with it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Both dateFormat and tomorrow are objects of Date() and they will never be equal to each other. That's why the condition is not satisfied and notification has not been sent. Instaed you can try this,

```
if(dateFormat.getTime() == tomorrow.getTime()) {
// Send notification 
}
```

Comment: Put some effort by debugging the application. Nothing is impossible. These are not conceptual doubts. It wouldn't take more than 5 mins to solve the problem by yourself.

Comment: I have, but I can't seem to figure out the reason why it won't send

Answer (score 0):

Every Service has its own Context, just use the that. Change `getApplicationContext()` by `YourServiceClass.this`.

```
 GoogleSignInAccount account = GoogleSignIn.getLastSignedInAccount(YourServiceClass.this);
                        if (account != null) {
                            String firstname = account.getGivenName();
                            mContentTitle = "Your " + name + " is about to be expired!";
                            mContentText = firstname + ", make sure to cook or eat your " + name + " by " + date;
                        }
```

Comment: Is there any exception you are getting?

Comment: I dont believe so